# Proving Language is Non Regular Using Pumping Lemma

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I am working on a question where I have the formal language Z over the alphabet Q {a, b, c} and it is generated by the context-free grammar whose non-terminals are S, A, and
B, the start symbol is S, production rules are as follows:

```
(1) S → abSb
(2) S → A
(3) A → Bc
(4) B → cA
(5) A → a
```

The question asked to describe the structure of strings in the language and I came up with $Z = \{w ∈ Q^* | w = ab^n o u o b^m, u ∈ Q^*, n, m ∈ N^*\}$. ($o$ means concatenated here).

I am now struggling with the second part of the question where I am asked to show this language isn't regular using the pumping lemma. I understand the concept of the pumping lemma and I have applied to simpler questions but I have never used it for a language involving concatenation.

Most examples I have seen online have been of structure $L = \{0^n 1 0^n 1 | n ∈ N^*\}$. I am wondering if there is some rule I am missing that says the powers must be the same or if I have gone wrong in my definition of the language.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Thanks @rici I was having some trouble lol

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested expression, $$Z = \{w ∈ Q^* \mid  w = ab^n Q^* b^m\},$$

is wrong.  As you suspected, the language is irregular only if there is something forcing the number of $\mathtt b$s to be the same.  In this case, there is.  *If* the language were actually $\mathtt{ab}^nQ^*\mathtt{b}^m$, it would be regular.

**Hint**: Note that the only way to eliminate  $B$ from a term is to replace it with ${\mathtt c}A$.  Let's produce an equivalent grammar that doesn't use $B$.   To do this, we drop the rule $B \to {\mathtt c}A$ completely, and then instead of $A\to B{\mathtt c}$, have $A\to {\mathtt c}Ac$.  (Do you understand why this works?)

Now the grammar is $$\begin{align}
S&\to \mathtt{ab}S\mathtt{b}\\
S&\to A \\
A&\to \mathtt{c}A\mathtt{c}\\
A&\to \mathtt{a}
\end{align}
$$

Perhaps this will be easier to handle?

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you so would I be correct in saying  the structure of strings in the language  would be $Z = \{w \in Q^* | w = ab^n Q^*b^n, n \in N^*\}$

Comment: I don't think that is correct either.  I suggest that you work through the grammar and try to make every possible string of length at most 6.  Then you can compare this list with your proposed structure to see if the structure predicts strings that aren't on the list, or if there is a string on the list that doesn't match the structure you guessed.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused I generated a few words and what I see is ab and b must repeat the same number of times and what is in between them then can be any combination of terminals from the alphabet

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore rule 1) then you get a subset $L_c$ of the language consisting of strings $s_n = c^nac^n$.

For large enough $n$'s the pumping lemma should be applicable to any $s_n$, so some non-empty substring $y$ of $s_n$ can be replicated arbitrary number of times.

This substring cannot contain $a$ because having more than one $a$ is only possible by introducing $b$'s from rule 1), but the replication result cannot contain $b$'s.

This means that substring $y$ would be inside of one of $c^n$ substrings. But replicating such $y$ would disbalance $c$'s, i.e., the resulting substring would look $c^mac^n$ with $m \neq n$.

P.S. About the language and its strings:
We can use (1) some number of times ($n$), but once we use (2) we can't never get back. This means that at some stage we have intermediate result $(ab)^nAb^n$. After that we can alternate between (3) and (4) some number ($m$) of times to get $(ab)^nc^mAc^mb^n$, but to finish we will eventually use (5) and end up with $(ab)^nc^mac^mb^n$, which is the format of all strings in $Z$.

P.S.2 There is an intuitive explanation why $Z$ is not regular. All regular languages can be parsed by finite automata. But after $(ab)^n$ is parsed the automaton must remember $n$ somehow so that it can check the number of $b$'s at the end. Since $n$ can be arbitrarily large one might need unlimited memory to remember it, which a finite automaton does not have.

Comment: I'm a bit lost, Do you think my original deduction of string structure is correct?

Comment: @ReneeOfadu: I'd expect $(ab)^n...b^n$, i.e., the number of $(ab)$'s on the left to be the same as the number of $b$'s on the right.   Not sure what $u$ stands for.

Comment: $u$ is meant to be any letter from my alphabet Q

Comment: I believe a general form for the strings is $(ab)^mc^nac^nb^m$

Comment: Could you explain a bit where you got that from?

Comment: @ReneeOfadu: I've edited my answer to include the explanation.